# How is a negative image figured out?

Tags: vb.net, image

My program im working on does grayscale, builds an alpha mask, and splits the color channels.
How do you invert a picture?

the above are done looking at the image pixel by pixel.

Im using vb2005.net, for the sake of speed is there other ways of doing those things using drawing.graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-invert.php). You'll basically have to use either `ColorMatrix`:

```
new float[][]
{
   new float[] {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
   new float[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
}
```

or [unsafe processing](http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.html) (not sure if this particular one can be done in VB.NET)

Comment: The first sentence of that article is wrong - it's implementing lumainversion ( inverting the luma channel value in HSL space by inverting  each colour channel in RGB space ) but says you invert the colours ( cromainversion - mapping each pixel to the opposite colour by adding 180 degrees to hue in HSL space ).